# Python HTTP Server to activate Code

Tags: python, http

I am trying to setup a python script that I can have running all the time and then use a HTTP command to activate an action in the script. So that when I type a command like this into a web browser:

```
http://localhost:port/open
```

The script executes a piece of code.

The idea is that I will run this script on a computer on my network and activate the code remotely from elsewhere on the network.
I know this is possible with other programming languages as I've seen it before, but I can't find any documentation on how to do it in python.
Is there an easy way to do this in Python or do I need to look into other languages?

Comment: Of course you can do this in Python. The easiest way, just as in most other languages, is to pick a web services framework (probably a lightweight one like Flask, rather than something like Django, but you can use whatever you like). But it's only slightly more complicated to use a raw HTTP server like the one in the stdlib and code up a hook to run a function for a given endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to select a web framework. I will recommand using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), since it is lightweight and really easy to start using it fast.

We begin by initializing your app and setting a route. `your_open_func()` (in the code below) which is decorated with the `@app.route("/open")` decorator will be triggered and run when you will send a request to that preticular url (for example `http://127.0.0.1:5000/open`)

As [Flask's website](http://flask.pocoo.org/) says: flask is fun. The very first example (with minor modifications) from there suits your needs:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/open")
def your_open_func():
    # Do your stuff right here.
    return 'ok'  # Remember to return or a ValueError will be raised.
```

In order to run your app `app.run()` is usually enough, but in your case you want other computers on your network to be able to access the app, so you should call the `run()` method like so: **`app.run(host="0.0.0.0")`.**

By passing that parameter you are making the server publicly available.